# If $M\bigoplus N $ submodule $A\bigoplus B$ does it imply either $M$ submodule $A$ or $M$ submodule $ B$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

> If $M\bigoplus N$ is a submodule of $A\bigoplus B$ does it necessarily  imply either $M$ is a submodule of $A$ or $M$ is a submodule of $B$?

If in general it is not true, is it true if $M$ and $N$ are $\mathbb Z$-modules?

I tried finding counter examples when they are $\mathbb Z$-modules but did not succeed.

Comment: What does it mean for $M\oplus N$ to be a subset of $A\oplus B$? Do we have $M\subseteq A\oplus B$, $N\subseteq A\oplus B$, and the direct sum is internal on the left hand side?

Comment: If it seems «very obvious» you should declare example hunting season started, for your intuition needs series adjusting!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Yes you are right. My intuition was thoroughly wrong. Thanks for pointing it out.  I fixed the question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No,

Let $A,B = \mathbb{Z}$ as $\mathbb{Z}$-modules.  Let $M$ be the submodule of $A\oplus B$ generated by $(2,1)$ and let $N$ be the submodule generated by $(0,1).$  Then $M\oplus N \subset A\oplus B$ but $M$ is not a subset of $A$ or $B.$

Answer (score 1):

No, in either cases really.

Consider $V=\bigoplus_{p\in\Bbb P}\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ (where $\Bbb P$ is all the prime integers). Now partition $\Bbb P$ into $A,B$ and $A',B'$ such that neither $A\subseteq A'$ nor $B\subseteq B'$, and consider the decompositions defined by $A,B$ and $A',B'$ as counterexamples.

Comment: I'm actually interpreting this as $A\nsubseteq A'$ and $A\nsubseteq B'$ and $B\nsubseteq A'$ and $B\nsubseteq B'$, and vice versa.